# IIS Application "Physical Path" is empty after creating via C#

Tags: c#, iis-7.5

I am executing the `AddApplication` sample method from the learn.iis.net site:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/285/provisioning-sample-in-c/

The method looks like this:

```
public static bool AddApplication(string siteName, string applicationPath, string applicationPool, string virtualDirectoryPath, string physicalPath, string userName, string password)
{
   ...
}
```

I am passing in the arguments:

```
siteName = "Default Web Site"
applicationPath = "/MyApp"
applicationPool = "MyAppPool"
virtualDirectoryPath = "/MyApp"
physicalPath = @"c:\dev\path\"
userName = null
password = null
```

After calling the AddApplication method, I go to IIS Manager and I can see the new app was created.  No exceptions are thrown, and everything looks good when I step through the method.  However, when I right click and go to "Advanced Settings", I see that the "Physical Path" entry is empty.

I have verified that the path exists.  I have tried physicalPath both with and without the trailing backslash.  I have tried passing my username and password as the last 2 args.  I have tried changing the app pool to run with an identity which is an administrative user (in case it's permission-related).

I'm running out of guesses.  I can't seem to find any examples of calling this AddApplication method... maybe I just don't understand what I'm supposed to be passing for arguments...?

I'm running Win7 Pro, IIS 7.5.

**Update:
Turns out that changing the virtualDirectoryPath to "/" solves my problem.  I'm not sure why that's true, but if someone could answer that, I am interested to understand this better.  Thanks.**

Comment: have you tried it using string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"); to get the physical path?

Comment: can you also try using double / it should work with or without virtual directory so for an example ~//content/images

Comment: Having the same problem using AppCmd from Command Line. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is related? http://serverfault.com/questions/496092/changing-physical-path-on-iis-through-appcmd-isnt-activated Did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: Jishi, I never did figure this one out except for the workaround of setting virtualDirectoryPath to '/'.  Let me know if you get further than me.